# Проверка на правильность внешнего ключа

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Программно создаю 2 таблицы в БД: Term(семестр) и Group(группа). Вот код этих таблиц.

```
    String term = "CREATE TABLE Term (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE," +
        "name TEXT NOT NULL);";

    String group = "CREATE TABLE _Group (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE," +
        "idTerm INTEGER NOT NULL," +
        "name TEXT NOT NULL," +
        "FOREIGN KEY(idTerm) REFERENCES Term(id));";
```

Затем я заполнил таблицу Term данными:

```
id | name
---------
1  | "1 семестр"
2  | "2 семестр"
```

Далее если выполнить команду

```
INSERT INTO _Group (idTerm, name) VALUES (10, 'КНТ-001');
```

То она выполнится без ошибок, и запись добавится в таблицу. Хотя внешний ключ будет ссылаться на несуществующую запись. Это неправильное поведение БД. Оно не должно разрешать мне добавлять запись с внешним ключем, который ссылается ни на что (ссылаюсь на 10-й id, а имею только 1 и 2). Кажется, раньше всегда во всех БД что меня учили эта функция стояла автоматически, а здесь необходимо ее включить как-то? Мне кажется что не хватает какой-нибудь команды при создании самой таблицы `_Group`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все верно, что бы использовать функции и ограничения внешнего ключа, то вам нужна библиотека собранная без ключей `SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY` или `SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER`. Если библиотека собрана с этими ключами, то вам нужно включить поддержку ограничений первичного ключа при помощи команды:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Проверить, определен ли параметр `foreign_keys` можно командой `PRAGMA foreign_keys;` (Будет 0 если выключена)

Документация: [2. Enabling Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Comment: что означает "библиотека собранная без ключей SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY" ? Под библиотекой вы имеете ввиду БД? Я ее просто создаю программно командой SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(dbName);

Comment: интересно то, что я программно создаю файл БД, а затем программно создаю в нем таблицы. Затем, если открыть этот файл с помощью DB Browser for SQLite, и выполнить команду PRAGMA foreign_keys то вернется 1, если добавить запись с отсылкой на несуществующий id, то появляется ошибка. Все как нужно.

Но, если я создам такую же запись программно на C# - ошибки не появляется и запись добавляется в таблицу. 

Почему-то когда я делаю это программно - проверки нет, а когда делаю это через DB Browser for SQLite - проверка есть. Почему так?

Comment: 1. База данных это не только хранилище на диске, это ещё и код, который имплементирует работу с этим хранилищем (язык, логика и т.д.) именно он обрабатывает ваши SQL команды. Код может быть как уже скомпилированный в исполняемые файлы и библиотеки либо представлен как набор исходного кода. Если у вас если исходный код, то вы можете самостоятельно его скомпилировать [определив набор констант](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) (ключей), которые влияют на конфигурацию базы данных.

Comment: 2. Правильно, эта функция включается для каждого подключения отдельно: "so must be enabled separately for each database connection"